# Any file download in Chrome keeps popping up Open xdg-open?

Tags: google-chrome, downloads, xdg-open

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 and all common required applications. However, in Chrome when I try to download a file (of any file extension), Chrome keeps popping up a message with text Open xdg-open? Nothing happens if I click on "Open xdg-open". I am stuck with this problem and cannot solve this.

[image]

Is there any handler registered that is mis-configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem by removing Fake (unofficial) IDM (Internet Download Manager) Chrome Extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idm-integration-extension/beobjkkhmebdklhjedacliojimbibppm

Note that it was installed when I was on Windows, and it got its way where via Chrome Sync.

Thanks.